# PHP - Create group of number ranges between two static numbers

Tags: php, numbers, range, grouping

I want to make a simple algorithm in PHP that has as scope to **generate automatically group of numbers** between a range.

Let me be more clear to you. I have a price filter section for an e-shop collection page. What I do is I'm grabbing the minimum and the maximum price from the database of products, then I would like to **create groups of those numbers**.

---

Let's suppose that the **minimum price** of a product is 50 dollars and the **maximum** one is 300 dollars. 
What I would like to do is something like this:

> Choose price range:
>
> [checkbox here] 50 - 100
>
> [checkbox here] 101 - 150
>
> [checkbox here] 151 - 200
>
> [checkbox here] 201 - 250
>
> [checkbox here] 251 +

So at the end to grab automatically the min and max value and create automatically groups.

I started something like this, but I'm stuck:

```
for ( $x = $minPrice; $x < $maxPrice; $x++ ) { 

    if ( $x % 50 == 0 ) {

        echo $x;

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can make your loop more efficient (i.e. loop less times) by incrementing by `50`. So instead of `$x++` doing `$x += 50`

Comment: Not putting too much effort / testing into it, but take a look: [https://3v4l.org/PNnca](https://3v4l.org/PNnca). You could change the function to receive the number of ranges you want insteand, and then divide to know the diff in each step

Comment: @FirstOne Thank you buddy! This is the answer. Works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code as much I'm able to understand you are expecting:

```
$range = "";
for($i = 0; $i <= 300; $i += 50) {
    $range = $i<250 ?  ($i.'-'.($i+50)) : "250+";
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$i.'">Range '.$range.'<br>'; 
}
```